# Swagger Version Error

Tags: node.js, centos, asterisk, swagger

I have Swagger Version Error :

cat connect.js :

```
/*jshint node:true*/
'use strict';

var ari = require('ari-client');
var util = require('util');

ari.connect('http://localhost:8088', 'sa', 'test', clientLoaded);

// handler for client being loaded
function clientLoaded (err, client) {
if (err) {
throw err;
}
}
```

and when I try : #node connect.js - it returns :

[ 'This API is using a deprecated version of Swagger!  Please see http://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki for more info' ]

Answer (score 0):

This message simply means that the server you're connecting to is based on the Swagger 1.2 specification or earlier.  Swagger is now at 2.0.

The message you're getting also tells me that you're using a very old client.  You shouldn't see the reference to Wordnik in any client made in the last 1.5 years.

Comment: how to update it ? when I write npm install -g swagger it doesn't install the last version